# Questions on creating OAuth 2.0 Server

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I'm in the process of designing an API to service a browser web app. I want to design the API in a way where if the need arises, it can be used cross platform. For the first stage I want to implement user name and password authentication (I believe the terminology is grant_type = password). I've read up on OAuth 2.0 being a standard in practice and I have a few questions:

1. Is there a suggested way of binding tokens and token expiry dates to users in the database? Can this be done in one table, or is it better to keep them separate?
2. I want to polish up and verify username and password authentication works before exploring into having 3rd party authentication (Facebook, Google+, Twitter, etc...) Is there anything I should know ahead of time when creating the database tables and API to make sure it is extendable into these features?
3. I'm hearing a lot about JWT, is this considered a standard way of generating and returning tokens to the front end?

I am looking to build the api in PHP and I was going to use the implementation from https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php but it looks like it is failing on php versions 7 and up. (I'm going to use 7.2 for this project) It may also be easier to create it myself one piece at a time.

Any direction or insight into the above would be greatly appreciated. This will be my first stab at implementing an extendable authentication framework in an app.

Comment: if it's just `mcrypt` that is the issue in 7, it's not that hard to refactor, I just refactored some code for that same reason.  That said this question is likely to be view as opinion based and off topic. :-(

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on the build failure! I'll take a look into that. As far as the question being opinion based, I apologize it came across as that. I'm new to using OAuth 2.0 and I'm just looking for what is today's standards.

Comment: Yea I just replaced it with PHPSecLib, but it was for AES encryption, which uses `mcrypt`, I don't know what they use if for, I did the 10 second look on their issues page.

Comment: Looking like random string generation for the token. What is weird is that code shouldn't be reached as it will check to see if the non deprecated function random_bytes will return before attempting the deprecated function mcrypt_create_iv.

Comment: Yea they probably patched it by now, I didn't dig to deep. There were a few other things in 7 that could cause issues, they made overriding classes a bit more strict for the typing of arguments,  and some changes to variable named constants `Class::$constant` now you need to do `Class::{$constant}` before it would recognize that `$contant=foo` was a string. Now it thinks its an undefined static property etc.